# How to implement Java function that returns a Type based on user's choice?

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to implement this method that accepts a database's row and column name, and it returns the value in that cell. The type that the user expects is specified by them via `Class<T> type`.

```
// This return T, the value under the columnName in the row.
public <T> T getColumnByName(Row row, String columnName, Class<T> type)
```

And I have access to this object called `Row` which conveniently gives me methods like:

```
row.getString(String columnName) // Gets String stored under column
row.getLong(String columnName) // Gets the Long stored under column
etc...
```

So it's quite basic, but I'm getting a little stuck regarding the generics. I tried to implement `getColumnByName` this way:

```
private <T> T getColumnByName(Row row, String name, Class<T> type) {
  if (type == Long.class) {
    return row.getLong(name);
  } else if (type == String.class) {
    return row.getString(name);
  } ... continued...
}
```

However, I get an error "Incompatible types, required: T, found: long".
I'm not sure how to deal with converting the concrete type that `Row` methods return to the generic type that the compiler would accept.

Any ideas for how this could be done?

Comment: @YugSingh, I don't think this is a duplicate of that because that is C# whereas this is Java.

Comment: Java generics are a different beast than C# generics, so I don't think it's a duplicate. The accepted answer (that it's better to just write a different method at each type) still holds, but the actual operational answer differs for Java. (I.e. you can't just write a cast to type T.)

Comment: Noted. Thanks, yes the accepted answer is helpful.

Comment: @Nick: You actually *can* just write a cast to type `T`, though it's not a great practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Class<T>` the user passed in to convince the compiler of the correctness of your code, though it does add the overhead of an extra runtime cast:

```
private <T> T getColumnByName(Row row, String name, Class<T> type) {
  if (type == Long.class) {
    return type.cast(row.getLong(name));
  } else if (type == String.class) {
    return type.cast(row.getString(name));
  } ... continued...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I might also consider refactoring the code such that it doesn't require this if/else checking if this is indeed an anti-pattern as the dupe question suggests.